# IOS: recover a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode

In my project in xcode I replace for error a viewcontroller (.h and .m) where I had a lot of code...is there a way to recover these view controller? 
I don't have snaphot for my project...

Comment: Just as with any other file, no unless you have a backup. If you have time machine configurate you might have a change. Let this be a lesson  and start using a SCM, like Git or Subversion (both can be used locally).

Comment: Go to the folder and try to do undo by command+z keys.

Comment: If you have no backup there is no chance, Sorry. If you have backup try with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have clicked on "**Remove Reference**", the reference is removed from the Xcode but the file is safe in your project's root folder.
You can add View Controller back by 
RightClick On Project - > Add New Files to Project -> Browse to root folder of your project and select the viewController.

If you have clicked on "**Move To Trash**", the files have been deleted from root folder as well, you need to find it in trash and copy to root folder and then follow the above step to add it back to XCode.

Comment: He did not remove the viewController, he override his old code with a new one.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I thought he removed his ViewController.